# Why isn't this format invalid?

Tags: python

```
for skill in skills if skill != "engineering":
   ...
```

skills is a list, and I want to do a check when iterating through the list.

Comment: Because that isn't valid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct version

```
for skill in skills: # <- with :
   if skill != "engineering": # <- with new indention
       ...  # <- with new indention
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

```
for skill in [skill for skill in skills if skill != "engineering"]:
```

Comment: Looks like it repeats twice

Answer (score 1):

Needs to be separate lines and your for loop line needs to end with a colon as well as your if statement.

```
skills = ['test','testing', 'engineering']

for skill in skills: 
  if skill != "engineering":
    print(skill)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter

```
for skill in filter(lambda skill: skill != "engineering", skills):
```

This is much more readable. If your filtering requires more logic, you can easily replace the lambda expression with a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out any skill that doesn't equal `'engineering'` then you can use `filter`:

```
for skill in filter('engineering'.__ne__, skills):
```

I personally prefer this over a `lambda`

Answer (score 0):

`for skill in skills if skill != "engineering":` is invalid because in Python, explicit `for` loops take the form:

```
for item in collection:
```

This line has four parts

1. the `for` statement
2. `item`, the current element in the iteration
3. the `in` operator
4. the collection being iterated over

The code in the question doesn't match this format, so it's syntactically invalid.

However Python also has implicit `for` loops inside constructions known as comprehensions.  A simple comprehension for creating list - known as a list comprehension - looks like:

```
new_list = [thing for thing in collection]
```

This line consists of:

1. A variable which points to the created list (`new_list`)
2. The assignment operator `=`
3. A pair of square brackets `[ ]`, denoting that the result will be a list
4. The item that will be added to the new list
5. `for` clause denoting the implicit `for` loop
6. The current item from the iteration
7. The `in` operator
8. The collection being iterated over

The code from the question looks as if it has been taken from a list comprehension that includes a condition, which would be of the form

```
new_list = [thing for thing in collection if some_condition_is_true]
```

The [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/index.html#the-python-tutorial) has an excellent [section on list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which includes coverage of more complex types - multiple loops and / or conditions.  There are also dictionary and set comprehensions that create dictionaries and sets; [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) share a similar syntax but create generators rather than concrete collections.

Answer (score 0):

A solution:

```
skills = ["testing", "management", "engineering"]
    for skill in [skill for skill in skills if skill != "engineering"]:
        print("%s" % skill)
```

Output:

```
>>>python test.py 
testing
management
```